# How to store PHP constants in a MySQL db

Tags: php, mysql, constants

I need to create a bunch of feeds in a fixed width format, they're all relatively the same in layout, but they can all have different formats.

For example:

> ```
> Field 1 can be 30 bytes wide, left justified and padded with 0s
> Field 2 can be 20 bytes wide, right justified padded with spaces
> ```

I'd like to store parameters for php's str_pad in the DB, but don't know the best way to store the pad_type parameter, since it's a constant, I can't read it back like:

```
$field = str_pad($input, $width, $pad_string, $pad_type)
```

I suppose I could wrap an `eval()` around `$pad_type`, but that seems sketchy.

Is there a better way to do this?

I'm stuck with, PHP 5.0, MySQL 4

Comment: In your example $pad_type is a variable, not a constant. Is the code example incomplete?

Comment: This is the only thing I could think of after reading the question: *What?*  I have no idea what you are trying to do.  Could you please try to explain it a little better?

Comment: $pad_type  would be a variable returned from a query, sorry for being too vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`constant()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php):

```
$value = constant('NAME_OF_THE_CONSTANT_AS_STORED_IN_DB');
```